# No crea directorio

Tags: android

Llevo un par de semanas intentando que esta funcion me cree un directorio. El telefono tiene una API 29 y Android 10 y no lo crea, pero en un telefono API 28 y Android 9 si funciona perfectamente.

He probado de todo lo que se me ha ocurrido pero no crea nada. Estan todos los permisos porque si lo crea en el segundo telefono que funciona bien.

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void copiaDatabase(){
        try {
            String DBName = "tesoreria.db";
            File pathdestino = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File pathorigen = getActivity().getDatabasePath(DBName);


            //if (pathdestino.canWrite()) {

                String destinoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File directorio = new File(destinoPath + File.separator + CARPETA);
                if (!directorio.exists()) {
                    directorio.mkdirs();
                }

                File subdirectorio = new File(directorio + File.separator + SUBCARPETA);
                if (!subdirectorio.exists()) {
                    subdirectorio.mkdir();
                }

                String origenDBPath = pathorigen.toString();
                String destinoDBPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + CARPETA + File.separator + SUBCARPETA + File.separator + DBName;
                File destinofichero = new File( destinoDBPath );
                if (!destinofichero.exists()) {
                    destinofichero.delete();
                }

                File origenDB = new File(origenDBPath);
                File destinoDB = new File(destinoDBPath);

                FileChannel origen = new FileInputStream(origenDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel destino = new FileOutputStream(destinoDB).getChannel();
                destino.transferFrom(origen, 0, origen.size());
                origen.close();
                destino.close();
            //}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar la Copia de Seguridad. Intentelo más tarde.")
                    .setTitle("ERROR Copia de Seguridad")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.apoyo24)
                    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                    });
            alertDialogCopiaError.show();
        }
}
```

Comment: estas trabajando con c# o java?

Comment: Esoy trabajando con JAVA

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

Despues de darle un monton de vueltas para Android 10 y API 29 para poder acceder a los documentos publicos a si como crear directorios sed debe de poner en el AndroisManifest.xml en la parte de < Aplicacion ....   esto

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"